# How to subtract floats inside of a vector2 in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity game and was trying to do something like this:

```
public GameObject player;
public float playerX;
public float playerY;
private Transform trsm;
playerX = player.GetComponent<Transform>().position.x;
playerY = player.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y;
trsm.position = new Vector2(playerX - 0.4, playerY);
```

However, I get this error:

```
Assets\trackPlayer.cs(23,41): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 
'float'
```

Does anyone know why this is and how I could fix it?

Update: Why am I perm-banned and getting down voted for this question?

Comment: When you write a decimal number like this `0.2` you are declaring the value as Type `decimal`.  Add an `f` to the end to indicate it is a float, eg. `0.2f`.

Comment: @hijinxbassist `0.2` is a `double` literal. `0.2m` would be a `decimal`.

Comment: @hijinxbassist pls post that as answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel  You are correct, I wasn't thinking straight.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number type is inferred to be of Type `double` because no suffix is present.
Since there is no implicit conversion between `double` and `float`, you get a conversion exception.
Adding the correct suffix to the value solves the issue by letting the compiler know what Type the number is.

```
Type      |  Suffix
----------|--------
float     |  f
double    |  d
decimal   |  m
uint      |  u
long      |  l
ulong     |  ul
```

Example

```
trsm.position = new Vector2(playerX - 0.4f, playerY);
```